# How can select a miniforge3 interpreter in Pycharm on my M1 mac?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm facing an issue regarding `PyCharm` an `Miniforge3`. I need `Miniforge3` in order to install `Tensorflow` on my `M1 mac`. The installation of `Miniforge3` works fine. I can also activate the corresponding environment in the terminal. No issues here. But when I try to use this environment in `PyCharm`, I get strange responses. What did I do:

## Steps to Reproduce

1. I created a clean new project.
2. Then I chose a new environment: [Selecting environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBANc.png)
3. Then the following happens: [Invalid Python SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xllbM.png)
4. The strange thing is, that I'm not even on python 3.10, but on 3.9. In the terminal I can see the right interpreter and the version: [Path to interpreter and python Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY0Iz.png)
5. And of course the interpreter is empty:[Empty interpreter in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYG2.png)

I'm on Pycharm `2021.2.1` (Professional Edition):

PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Professional Editio
Build #PY-212.5080.64, built on August 25, 2021
Licensed to ———-
Subscription is active until April 30, 2022.
Runtime version: 11.0.11+9-b1504.16 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.5.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

Obviously the mistake was how I created the virtual environment. Seems as if I didn't understand how it really works. I had to clone the base environment like this:

```
conda create --clone base --name tf
```

Then PyCharm recognised the new environment!